# TemplateSyntaxError 'staticfiles' is not a valid tag library'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm having a really strange issue trying to get the `staticfiles` taglib working in my application. I'm essentially getting the following error:

```
'staticfiles' is not a valid tag library: Template library staticfiles not found, tried django.templatetags.staticfiles,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.staticfiles
```

Here's my template which is throwing this error:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "styles/bootstrap-1.2.0.min.css" %}">
        {% endblock %}
        <title>{% block title %}Tzibor{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>It Works!</h1>
        {% block scripts %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" %}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (

)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': '/tmp/project.db',
        'USER': '',                    
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
MEDIA_ROOT = '' # abs fs path to upload dir
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

SECRET_KEY = '4qo&twl!=ty!n%1@h2nidz^ie@$^uu@*pz)(ol%ise0&g6*@&_'

#TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
#   "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
#   "django.core.context_processors.debug",
#   "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
#   "django.core.context_processors.media",
#   "django.core.context_processors.static",
#   "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
#)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'project.web',
    'south',
)
```

Essentially, I followed the guide available [in Django's documentation on how to set up the static serving application,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and got this error. Can anyone see what the issue is? Am I missing something?

Full stacktrace [here](http://pastebin.com/cPNNGZYQ).

Comment: What happens when you go into the shell and type `import staticfiles`?

Comment: I guess that you did not set the `STATIC_ROOT` value in settings. Does `manage.py collectstatic` work fine?

Comment: @Jordan Reiter, `ImportError: No module named staticfiles`.

Comment: @Skirmantas, had that issue, fixed it, but still getting the error.

Comment: Try `import django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles` in `python manage.py shell`

Comment: There's no such package as "templatetags.staticfiles" in "django.contrib.staticfiles". I'm running things in Buildout, so is there another package other than Django proper which I need to include? I'm running Django 1.3.

Comment: My guess is there's something amiss with your Django install. I'd do a reinstall of Django and see what happens.

Comment: AFAIK This is new in the development version not in 1.3. See The first line for the [static tag in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) and compare the doc to version 1.3.

Comment: I did find what seems to be the tag in: [django.templatetags.static.py](http://pastebin.com/RrRWihuC).

Comment: That did the trick. It's weird that Django's docs default over to `dev` rather than their latest releas.

Comment: Provide an answer detailing using `{% load static %}` and `{% get_static_prefix %}` and I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You probably are running django 1.3 right!?

So, notice the difference between django dev(1.4) and django 1.3:

- 1.3 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag
- dev : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag

So if you wanna use "{% load staticfiles %}" u must be using django dev(1.4+)

This is how to use in django 1.3 :

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/hi.jpg" />
```