# django staticfiles with "With a template tag" method

Tags: django

I came from PHP, Python and Django are new to me. I have a simple problem but have already stuck with this for hours and still couldn't find out what went wrong.

I want to insert a simple image into the template.

I have followed 
[TemplateSyntaxError 'staticfiles' is not a valid tag library'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325196/templatesyntaxerror-staticfiles-is-not-a-valid-tag-library) and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag

Following are my settings.

1. my static folder is located in `/myproject/myapp/static/`. And the img path is `/static/images/hi.jpg`.
2. the src value in img tag is `"/static/images/hi.jpg"` when the page is rendered
3. Setting in setting.py

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'django.contrib.admin')
```

4. In template, I have

   ```
    {% load static %}
    {% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}
   ```

   and the source part of the image

   src="{{ STATIC_PREFIX }}images/hi.jpg"

5. finally, the url of the app is http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/

what part is wrongly configured? Any idea? Thank you so much for the help. Sorry for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urls.py you should add the static files urls:

```
# urls.py

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 2):

I use in html `{% load staticfiles %}`  and e.g.

`<img src="/static/images/loader.gif" alt="loader.gif"></img>`

or also

`<img src="{% static 'images/loader.gif %}" alt="loader.gif"></img>`

with **setting.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))    

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
        )

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and it works (Django 1.7 and Python3.4).